# How to rebase specified commit to different branch using SourceTree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I have the following situation:

[image: SourceTree Git log output]

How can I `rebase` last commit from staging (removed ProxyFinder...) onto `warning-fixes` using SourceTree?

One way would be to merge `staging` into `warning-fixes` and then reset `staging` to previous commit, but that sounds like nasty workaround.

Comment: Merging staging to warning-fixed is okay. It will do nothing to staging. In this very case you could also reset warning-fixes to staging.

Comment: But is it doable with rebase? - literaly to move commit and all its children to different branch that if changes are "mergable"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do it is as mentioned in [@ElpieKay's comment](//stackoverflow.com/questions/39768853/how-to-rebase-spiecified-commit-to-different-branch-using-sourcetree#comment66833577_39768853), and at the end of your question: merge `staging` into `warning-fixes` and then reset `staging` to previous commit.

To do it from the command line, do:

```
git checkout warning-fixes
git merge staging
git checkout staging
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

In SourceTree:

1. Double-click `warning-fixes` to check it out.
2. Right-click on `staging`.
3. Click `Merge staging into current branch`.
4. Double-click `staging` to check it out.
5. Right-click the previous commit, where `origin/staging` currently is.
6. Click `Reset current branch to this commit`.

The reason you don't want to use `rebase` is that it doesn't just move the commits, but it also moves the branch pointer. In this case, attempting to rebase `staging` onto `warning-fixes` would have no effect, since the commit at the tip of `staging` already has the same parent as the tip of `warning-fixes`.

The only real alternative is to use `cherry-pick`, but this will (by default) create a duplicate commit with a new committer date. (And it becomes a pain if you have more than one commit to move.)

Comment: As for `cherry-pick`, there will be a side effect in duplicated commits.

Comment: @Antoniossss Actually there won't be: since the commit you would `cherry-pick` has the same parent as the tip of `warning-fixes`, Git would reuse the commit and just move `warning-fixes` forward 1 commit.

Comment: it creates extra commit with the same content as cherry picked one in my case... why is that?

Comment: @Antoniossss Oops, my bad. I must have gotten that confused with the functionality of [Magit](//magit.vc/). Updated my answer.